# Regarding finite locally free modules.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with unity and $M$ an invertible $A$-module. Suppose that we have a surjection $\varphi: A^{2} \to M$ with $\varphi(e_1)=m_1, \varphi(e_2)=m_2$ and suppose further that we have $a_1,a_2 \in A$ such that $$a_1m_2 - a_2m_1=0.$$

Does this imply that the module  $M\cong A$?

Comment: Probably you want to say $\ker\varphi\ne0$.

Comment: @user26857 that is an automatic consequence of the condition.  In particular, we have $\varphi(a_1e_2 - a_2e_1) = 0$

Comment: I presume you meant at least one of $a_i\neq 0$, otherwise the condition is vacuous. The answer is no. If $A$ is Dedekind domain, for any invertible module, what you say is true, but if it is not a pid, there are many such $M$ not isomorphic to $A$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Really? The condition is fulfilled for $(a_1,a_2)=(0,0)$.

Comment: @user26857 aha, I assumed that $a_1,a_2$ were non-zero elements of $A$.